# How to stream iTunes content to Apple TV 2G without a Mac or PC?

Tags: itunes, music, appletv, streaming

I would like to upgrade my 1st-gen Apple TV and was wondering if it is possible to stream to new Apple TV from a NAS drive with iTunes server or an alternate method. I am not willing to go XBMC way since I would like to control my Apple TV though the Remote app for iOS.

Comment: The AppleTV does not understand network files.  You need some Apple device to send the video streams.

Answer (score 2):

You can play media that originates on an iOS device using AirPlay to send it to the Apple TV. AirPlay is built in to iOS.

If you have a PC or Mac, you could turn on iTunes Match and send the entire library to the cloud. At that point, you could ditch the PC/Mac and let Apple TV play from the cloud. iTunes Match requires a yearly subscription fee.

Neither of these features requires you to have a Mac or a PC, but neither helps much if all your media is on NAS.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to stream directly to the new Apple TV from a NAS.  You need a laptop/Mac in the middle.